# Context Name Different than WAR Name Possible with Tomcat Parallel Deployment

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

The application I am working on currently runs in production under multiple contexts within tomcat and we are doing so by creating separate context.xml files for each where we specify the docbase which points to the same directory in each file.  We are currently evaluating the parallel deployment feature of Tomcat and I'm having trouble finding a way to get that to work with our current setup.  I've read the tomcat documentation (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) and it doesn't appear to support our current setup, but I wanted to reach out to the community and ask before we change how we setup tomcat.  I have been able to get it to work if we create separate wars for each context and deploy them separately in the webapps folder.

Does anyone know if our current deployment mechanism can work with the parallel deployment process and if so, how would that be accomplished?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality by creating versioned context files that point at your web applications.  For example, if you have a context called myWebsite then you need to create a context file file called myWebsite.xml.  This will have the docBase value set for your application.  An example is provided below.

```
File:   /{tomcat.base}/conf/Catalina/localhost/myWebsite.xml
<Context reloadable="true" crossContext="true" docBase="/Users/jeremy/myapp"></Context>
```

Then you can do a parallel deploy by copying the application into it's new location (such as:  /Users/jeremy/myapp-v2), and then creating a new context file which will point at that new location.  The new context file should include the version number like all standard parallel deployments.

```
File:   /{tomcat.base}/conf/Catalina/localhost/myWebsite##001.xml
<Context reloadable="true" crossContext="true" docBase="/Users/jeremy/myapp-v2"></Context>
```

As soon as tomcat finds the new context file the new version of the application will be loaded and new users will be sent to the new version of the application.  Existing users will be migrated to the new version once their sessions expire.

Thanks to everyone on the tomcat user mailing list who helped me out on this  http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Tomcat-7-0-27-on-Mac-OSX-Lion-Is-it-Possible-to-use-Tomcat-Parallel-Deployment-when-the-Context-Namee-td5000908.html#a5000920